# How can I zip Node Lambda dependencies in AWS CDK stack?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, aws-cdk

I am using the CDK to create a simple serverless project with API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB. Seems pretty cool so far but I get the following error when I add an external dependency to the Lambda:

```
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './uuid-random'",
```

For clarity, I'm not asking what the problem is with this error, as that is well documented. I'm looking for help as my attempts to zip the dependencies have failed so far.

I have done my research, and I am not alone in this scenario. However, I'm a little confused with what path to take. I need to bundle my dependencies but all of the examples so far are fairly complex for what I am doing, and none of the examples fit. I have also seen suggestions of using `fromAsset`, but that didnt work either (cdk deploy just hung). So, I'd really appreciate any help in getting past this seemingly simple issue. TIA.

**Project structure:**

```
bin/
  cdkProject.js
handlers/
  api.js
lib/
  cdkProject-stack.js
node_modules/
test/
.gitignore
cdk.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

**Lambda (api.js)**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB;
const TABLE_NAME = process.env.TABLE_NAME || "";
const PRIMARY_KEY = process.env.PRIMARY_KEY || "";
const uuid = require('./uuid-random');

async function postProduct(event) {

  const params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
      "id": {
        S: uuid()
      },
      "name": {
        S: "Test Product 1"
      },
      "price": {
        N: "1.55"
      },
      "tags": {
        SS: [ "tag1","tag2" ] 
      } 
    }
  };

  try {
    const response = await db 
      .putItem(params)
      .promise()
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(err => err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
    return JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
  }
}

module.exports = {
  postProduct
}
```

Comment: what you need is separate node project for your handler. so, have a separate package.json for your handlers folder, fromAsset should point to the folder which has handler code along with its own node_modules. Even better is new folder for each lambda so, handlers/lambda1 ,handler/lambda2 ,etc each containing its own package.json and its dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally each lambda needs its own package.json which contains its own dependencies.

[image]

cdk code will refer it to the lambda folder as

```
const fn = new lambda.Function(this, "MyFunction", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
  handler: "index.handler",
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join("./handlers/test-uuid/")),
});
```

Comment: checked in to https://github.com/BaluVyamajala/my-node-cdk

Comment: Thanks @Balu Vyamajala I'm comparing your structure to mine and testing. Looks like your commit is missing the index.js but going by your image above, that lives in the `test-uuid` directory alongside the lambda level `package.json` right?

Comment: @johnny_mac you are correct. also, cdk by default added to ignore .js in .gitignore. I pushed it now.

Comment: Good solution! :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html) (previously `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs` CDK v1 - deprecated now) construct, which will bundle your lambda code and all of the dependencies using esbuild.

By default the construct will use Docker version of esbuild. But if you explicitly add esbuild to your project deps, then it will use the local version and you won’t need Docker.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with SAM well to run Lambda locally though.

Comment: this is the correct answer. and it does work with local SAM.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is based on Node.js, use **NodejsFunction**. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html).

It automatically transpiles and bundles the Lambda code and dependencies. Instead of defining a `package.json` for every Lambda function, dependencies can be fined in a single `package.json` (at root level).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever creating a lambda function, you should make sure the folder containing the handler function has a package.json file if you imported external dependencies in your lambda handler function.

Then, in that folder you can run `npm install` to produce a node_modules folder with all the dependencies installed based on package.json

```
bin/
  cdkProject.js
handlers/
  package.json
  api.js
  node_modules/
    ... installed dependencies
lib/
  cdkProject-stack.js
node_modules/
test/
.gitignore
cdk.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Finally, point your `lambda.Code.fromAsset` to the handlers folder.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is,
you need to upload the whole directory, instead of only index.js

for this, go to your src directory, then run `npm init`,
then install your required packages by running `npm install <package name>`

this will create package.json and package-lock.json and node_modules, inside your src directory

[image: src directory]

Now, when creating lambda function, provide the whole directory, instead of the index.js file, `code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "/../src/")),`

[image: creating lambda]

And finally, deploy your stack again.