# Lambda function with additional dependencies

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm starting a CDK lambda project which gets the source code like this:

```
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("resources"),
    handler: "synthetic_test.main",
```

There's a single javascript file `synthetic_test.js` in that folder.

This seems to work but I can't figure out how to make it so that I could do:

```
const axios = require("axios");
```

in that file.

For some reason it seems to be able to import:
`const AWS = require("aws-sdk");`
but nothing else.

I did `yarn add axios` which added it to the `package.json` of my CDK project. But that does not really seem to help the lambda a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The AWS Lambda runtime environment includes native language libraries and the relevant language-specific AWS SDK.

It does not contain arbitrary third-party packages. You need to either [package those dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html) with your code or create a Lambda Layer that includes the dependencies and configure your Lambda function to use the Lambda Layer.

To package CDK app dependencies, see [@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-lambda-nodejs-readme.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361096/how-can-i-zip-node-lambda-dependencies-in-aws-cdk-stack).

Comment: Is there an easy way to get that to work with `cdk watch`?

Comment: Do I just copy paste the minified axios source code into the js file?

Comment: Technically you could probably do that but, no, that's not a good solution. I added a link to a related answer. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe but this does not seem to be very common usage?

Comment: No, I'd say it's likely to be the norm. Most Lambda functions probably have non-AWS dependencies.

Comment: @Alper webpack is your way to go to "copy" minified source code :)

Comment: I got it to work like that but what does that do, bundle the `node_modules` directory together with the js?

Comment: You should be able to view the contents of the deployed ZIP file.

Comment: the relatively new aws-lambda-[language] libraries rely on the various dependency systems (package.json or requirements.txt or whatever) to build a custom docker image on the fly, installing your requirements into that docker image on deployment - which has been an option for lambdas forever, but is now bundled into the backend of cdk for incredible ease of use. I do not believe they will work with `cdk watch` - but they are none the less very cool for those of us who have done  years of layer management for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I went with packaging dependencies with my code

My cdk went to

```
//  define PUT account function
const putAccountLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "put-account-lambda", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
  handler: "main.handler",
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "/../src/put-account/dist")),
  environment: {
    REGION,
    ADMINS_TABLE,
    ADMINS_TABLE_PARTITION_KEY,
    HASH_ALG,
  }
})
```

With dist being the folder with a packed main.js file. And this file has a handler entrypoint. I had to update the package.json of these lambdas with packed dependencies.

```
{
    "name": "put-account",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode=production --env env=prod",
        "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development --env env=dev"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.66.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1058.0",
        "crypto": "^1.0.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    }
}
```

And I updated the package.json of my cdk project to these scripts.

```
"build": "tsc && npm run build:webpack",
"build:webpack": "for file in ./src/*; do (cd $file && npm i && npm run build) & done",
"build:beta": "tsc && npm run build:webpack:beta",
"build:webpack:beta": "for file in ./src/*; do (cd $file && npm i && npm run build:dev) & done",
```

Notice that my file structure is as follows:

```
./
bin
lib
src
package.json
```

With src holding the source code for my project's lambdas.

I am not sure if you are familiar with webpack, but I have divided my webpack configuration in common, dev, prod.

A dev webpack configuration is specially useful for debugging because otherwise you lose line numbers among other useful information when something goes wrong on runtime.

Comment: project github: https://github.com/gpspelle/cdk-e-commerce

Comment: Not having to learn webpack would be nice for a use case like this. Also, does this work with `cdk watch`?

Comment: Well, I didn't see learning webpack as a big burden. It was pretty straight forward, the only tip I recommend is dividing your configuration in dev and production. I am unsure of what `cdk watch` is and does.